# Supply Chain Spike Order Statistics

Tags: time-series, distributions, forecasting, anomaly-detection, augmented-dickey-fuller

I work in supply chain. I am trying to identify orders that could be classified as spikes. I need to do this across many thousands of different products, each with vary different demand/order patterns. I have three years of order data.

My initial approach was simply to assume a normal distribution (big assumption), calculate the mean and standard deviation for each product and use these parameters in a one-tailed test to calculate confidence bounds and any order that crossed these bounds could be considered a spike.

The more I read the more I think my model has some errors that need to be addressed.

My first question is in regards to statistical tests of this order data. First, does the data need to be transformed to stationary -- where it is non stationary -- if I am not forecasting time series but instead identifying data points within the time series order data that may be spikes? My second question is in regards to applying the Dickey Fuller stationarity test across thousand of different products with different demand/order patterns -- is this feasible or could this cause problems that I am not considering?

Comment: Also, are there any recommendations on an alternative model/approach that I should use to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to CV.SE, you might want to look up resources on "anomaly detection in time series".

Comment: Maybe [some of this posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=time+seri*+spike*+det*+answers%3A1) help?